# Не понимаю, как рассмотреть различные элементы последовательности, находящиеся на расстоянии на расстоянии не больше чем 7

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Задача: На вход программы поступает последовательность из N целых положительных чисел, все числа в последовательности различны. Рассматриваются все пары различных элементов последовательности, находящихся на расстоянии не больше чем 7 (разница в индексах элементов пары должна быть 7 или менее, порядок элементов в паре неважен). Необходимо определить количество таких пар, для которых сумма элементов не делится на 8.
Описание входных и выходных данных
В первой строке входных данных задаётся количество чисел N (8 ≤ N ≤ 1000). В каждой из последующих N строк записано одно целое положительное число, не превышающее 10 000.
В качестве результата программа должна вывести одно число: количество пар элементов, находящихся в последовательности на расстоянии не более чем 7, в которых сумма элементов не кратна 8.

```
var
  a: array[1..10000] of integer;
  N, i, j, x, b: integer;

begin
  x := 0;
  readln(N);
  for i := 1 to N do 
    readln(a[i]);
  for i := 1 to N-7  do
    for j := i to N do
      if ((a[i] + a[j]) mod 8 <> 0) then
        x := x + 1;
  writeln(x);
end.
```

Не знаю, как рассмотреть их на расстоянии не больше 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутренний цикл

```
for j := i + 1 to i + 7 do
```